# Can I add a style tag to a bokeh plot

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm writing a custom tooltip for my `bokeh` plot.  I'm sick of writing `style` attributes for every element.  How can I pass a `<style>` element to `bokeh` to use for my custom tooltips?

Comment: Example code will help to answer your question

Comment: @Leon I should know better ;-)  Will do.